# f# can't override KeyPressed event windows form

Tags: winforms, events, f#, overriding

I wrote the following code:

```
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing

let f = new Form(Text="Clock", TopMost=true)
f.Show()

type Editor() =
    inherit UserControl()

    override this.OnMouseDown e =
        printfn "Mouse Down"

    override this.OnKeyDown e =
        match e.KeyCode with
           | Keys.W -> printfn "W pressed"
           | _ -> printfn "Something else pressed"

let e = new Editor(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
f.Controls.Add(e)
```

The problem is that if i press "W" or another random Key i got no message on the console, why ?
For the mouse all is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `Editor` component does not have focus. Adding the following solves the problem:

```
e.Focus()
```

Comment: oh nice, so keyboards events need Focus while mouse events doesn't ?

Comment: apparently so - I'm not a WinForms expert though!